# Cascade updates on tables and pivot tables with laravel and Eloquent

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.5

I created a model nammed sector. For this model i created methods to make links between the database table :

- A sector has many valuechain with many segments, which have many
  keyneeds
- A valuechain has many segments
- A segment has many keyneeds ...

It has been translated this way :

```
public function valuechains()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Valuechain');
}
public function segments()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Segment', 'App\Valuechain');
}
public function keyneeds()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Keyneed', 'App\Segment', 'App\Valuechain');
}
```

When i soft delete a sector I want to create a cascade on other tables and make updates.

My destroy method is :

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $sector = Sector::findOrFail($id);
    // on update lang_sector pour chaque id
    $sector_ids = $sector->langs()->allRelatedIds();
    foreach ($sector_ids as $id){
        $sector->langs()->updateExistingPivot($id, ['lang_sector.deleted_at' => Carbon::now()]);
    }
    $sector->valuechains()->update(
        [
            'valuechains.deleted_at' => Carbon::now(),
            'valuechains.updated_at' => Carbon::now(),
        ]
    );
    $sector->segments()->update(
        [
            'segments.deleted_at' => Carbon::now(),
            'segments.updated_at' => Carbon::now(),
        ]
    );
    $sector->keyneeds()->update(
        [
            'keyneeds.deleted_at' => Carbon::now(),
            'keyneeds.updated_at' => Carbon::now()
        ]
    );

    Sector::where('id', $id)->delete();

    return redirect()->route('sectors.index')->with('success', 'Sector deleted');
}
```

I have pivot table for valuechains, segments and keyneeds and i also want to update the updated_at and deleted_at columns on those tables...

For those 3 tables i added to the model the lang method for defining the pivot relation and defining the fields i have inside the pivot table:

```
public function langs() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Lang')
        ->withPivot(
            'vcname',
            'vcshortname',
            'vcdescription',
            'vcshortdescription',
            'created_at',
            'updated_at',
            'deleted_at'
        );
}
```

I have an error message :

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Champ: 'updated_at' dans field list est ambigu (SQL: update `segments` inner join `valuechains` on `valuechains`.`id` = `segments`.`valuechain_id` set `valuechains`.`deleted_at` = 2018-05-09 07:34:30, `valuechains`.`updated_at` = 2018-05-09 07:34:30, `segments`.`deleted_at` = 2018-05-09 07:34:30, `segments`.`updated_at` = 2018-05-09 07:34:30, `**updated_at**` = 2018-05-09 07:34:30 where `valuechains`.`sector_id` = 2)